# Windows 8 Missing Installed Cultures

Tags: windows-8.1, cultureinfo

Is there a way to reinstall cultures for Windows 8?

I ran a windows update which took about 30 minutes.
When I was done I opened powershell and ran a check to see what cultures were installed and got no results.
[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultures([System.Globalization.CultureTypes]::InstalledWin32Cultures).lcid | sort-object

Then I ran it with AllCultures
[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultures([System.Globalization.CultureTypes]::AllCultures).lcid | sort-object

and got

```
LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             ----------- 
 4                zh-CHS           Chinese (Simplified) Legacy 
 31748            zh-CHT           Chinese (Traditional) Legacy
```

This is part of a reoccurring larger issue I've been having. Documented here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ea0f2d35-958b-4621-9a0b-84fb9a443800/import-data-tier-application-collation-1033-is-not-supported?forum=ssdt

Comment: I've followed up for requests for additional information from you on the SSDT forum thread. We've reached out to the Windows team for help but they need some extra information to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a repro, but I think what's happening is that a registry key is removed when the Taiwan language pack is removed (which can happen silently if you aren't using that language pack).  This could be because the OEM provided the language as one of many in case the customer needed it, but when the user hasn't set it, Windows will remove it to free up space.  The OEM may not notice because they're in Taiwan and wouldn't think to uninstall the language pack :)

If this happens, please try re-adding the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\ExtendedLocale registry key.

Either:

A) from an elevated command prompt:
 reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\ExtendedLocale

B) or in regedit, go to 
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls
 Edit->New->Key from the menu
“ExtendedLocale” for the name

This needs to be done AFTER the language pack is removed, so probably after you start seeing symptoms.  As I mentioned, I don't have a repro machine, so please let me know if this fixes it for you.

Thanks

Shawn Steele [Microsoft]